# Best way to upgrade SSD where OS is installed

Tags: windows-10, ssd, operating-systems, upgrade

im very new in building pc and i recently got a desktop with 250GB SSD and 1TB HDD. The OS is installed in the SSD and im thinking about upgrading the size of the SSD.
I would like to ask on what is the best way to upgrade the ssd? is there a way to clone my current ssd unto the new one? or should I just start with a fresh newly installed OS?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at CloneZilla.

Comment: We usually just clone the SSD. AIOMEI Partition Assistent free can do it too, just make sure you do one operation at a time. So clone to the bigger SSD without moving/resizing, then on the new disk, move partitions if you want that, as one task, then resize the main partition as one task.

Comment: Samsung Magician does exactly that if you have a Samsung SSD.